# Display progress bar while connecting web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I want to display a progress bar while waiting for the response from web service request. But during this time, the android progress bar is not loading.

```
 public class WebService extends Activity {

          private static final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
          private static final String METHOD_NAME="AddEmployee";
          private static final String URL="http://10.32.4.24/Android/AndroidBus.svc";
          private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/IAndroidBus/AddEmployee";

          String celsius;
          Button b;
          TextView tv;
          EditText et;
          String res,resultval;

          @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);

             et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
             tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
             b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
             b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   new service().execute();
                }
          });
    }

    private class service extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
         ProgressDialog pd;
         protected void onPreExecute(){
             pd=new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
             pd.show();
         }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            System.out.println("In DoIn Background");

            // Initialize soap request + add parameters
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("Name");
            pi.setValue(et.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty(pi);

                        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            setProgress(1);

            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE( URL);

                // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                String resdump=androidHttpTransport.responseDump.toString();
                System.out.println(resdump);
                setProgress(2);
                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                SoapPrimitive result=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                setProgress(3);
                if (result != null) {
                    // Get the first property and change the label text
                    // txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    res = result.toString();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return res;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String h) {
            String result = h;
            pd.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result + "°F");

        }

    }


}
```

I want to show a progress bar while sending and getting request/response.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is wrong. A progress set between SoapSerializationEnvelope, HttpTransportSE and Result ha no sense because huge work is made inside HttpTransportSE.call(...).
If you wish a really download/upload progress bar on number of byte received and send, you have to modify HttpTrasportSE class. In detail, you have to modify call() and read() of this class.

As you can see [here (HttpTransportSE.java)](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java), for example, for implementing upload progress, you have to create your HttpTransportSE, copy all original code and modify this portion:

```
public List call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers, File outputFile) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
(...)
OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();
os.write(requestData, 0, requestData.length);
os.flush();
os.close();
(...)
```

To this (i've considered common ProgressDialog):

```
public List call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers, File outputFile, ProgressDialog dialog)
    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    (...)

    if(dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setProgress(0);

            InputStream iss = new ByteArrayInputStream(requestData, 0, requestData.length);

            int byteCount = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            while (true) 
            {
                int rd = iss.read(buf, 0, 256);
                byteCount += rd;
                if (rd == -1)
                    break;
                os.write(buf, 0, rd);

                dialog.setProgress((int) (((float)byteCount/(float)requestData.length)*100));
            }
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            iss.close();
            buf = null;
        }
        else
            os.write(requestData, 0, requestData.length);

        os.flush();
        os.close();
(...)
```

As you can see you have to override call method adding new parameter (ProgressDialog or ProgressBar-type according to your purposes) and passing it your dialog/bar (if you pass 'null', default logic is considered).
This is the only way if you want progressbar shows real progress (by ksoap2).

For downloading, logic is the same. Find portion of code in which download is managed, save somewhere Content-Length value you can read from response header and implement similar upload "while" cycle for reading bytes considering content-length saved previously.

Hope this explanation can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a message to the progress dialog..

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
         pd=new ProgressDialog(WebService.this);
         pd.setMessage("Loading...");
         pd.setIndeterminate(true);
         pd.show();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try different context object here,

instead of this,

```
 ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
```

try

```
 ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
```

Comment: pd=new ProgressDialog(WebService.this);

Comment: yes exactly as @Nunu has suggested. Replace the ACtivityName.this with WebService.this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your setProgress call does, but assuming that it updates the progress dialog, you have to let your asynctask implement

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgress(progress);
 }
```

and call `publishProgress(2);` in your`doInBackground` instead of `setProgress`

This is because you can't update ui elements in doInBackGround method which runs on a different thread. Doing that, you are likely not only to not update the dialog, but also to break your application.

Answer (score 0):

**Four Steps, here we go..**

(1). *declear progress dialog in your activity*

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
```

(2). *start dialog when you starting AsyncTask class*

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CurrentActivity.this, "", "loading..");
```

eg.

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CurrentActivity.this, "", "loading search..");

SearchTask task= new GetSearchSeedsData();
task.execute(urlString);
```

(3). *do your heavy work (web-service or any) in doInBackground() method of AsyncTask class*

(4). *then dismiss progress dialog in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask class*

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: i asked for progress bar RDC not progress dialog

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/) may help dear